# I am not understanding why this is displaying out of order

Tags: javascript

I have an object.
I pull the keys and values and place in separate arrays.
I then put them back together but in reverse.  It keeps placing the second item first.

```
const obj = { keyname: 'Greg', keyage: 40, keyjob: 'cook'};
console.log(_.invert(obj));

    invert (object) {
      let keyArr = Object.keys(object);
      let valueArr = Object.values(object);
      const result = {};
      valueArr.forEach((value, i) => result[value] = keyArr[i]);
      return result;
    }
```

I am expecting to get a result of

```
{ Greg: 'keyname', 40: 'keyage', cook: 'keyjob' }
```

but instead i get

```
{ '40': 'keyage', Greg: 'keyname', cook: 'keyjob' }
```

why?

Comment: Keys that look like numbers always come first. The ordering of property names is defined in the spec but it is a very, very fragile practice to rely on it.

Comment: I was just looking up a different way to add them in.  I was unaware of ordering and am glad I have found this.  I was looking at object.assign and found my way to .map.  Thank you for the quick responses.